# Highcharts autoscale yaxis multiple plot bands issue

Tags: highcharts

I have an issue with dynamically updating a yAxis using the Axis.update method. When doing an update on the yAxis, if there is more than one plot band, the second plot band does not get removed when the yAxis is redrawn, so it is duplicated. I think this is probably an issue in the Highcharts (highstock) library, but I was wondering if anyone had experienced this and knows if I have just missed a setting.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/heeXA/

HTML:

```
<div id="chart"></div>
<button id="autoscale">Toggle autoscale</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#chart").highcharts({
    height: 350,
    yAxis: [{
        top: 50,
        height: 200,
        min: 0,
        max: 30,
        tickInterval: 4,
        plotBands: [{
            from: 12,
            to: 16,
            color: "#d9edf7",
            label: {
                "text": "Plot band 1"
            }
        }, {
            from: 20,
            to: 25,
            color: "#dff0d8",
            label: {
                text: "Plot band 2"
            }
        }]
    }],
    series: [{
        type: "line",
        yAxis: 0,
        data: [1, 5, 9, 15, 19, 21, 26, 9]
    }]
});

$("#autoscale").on("click", function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("autoscaled");
    var autoscaled = $(this).hasClass("autoscaled");
    var chart = $("#chart").highcharts();
    chart.yAxis[0].update({
        min: autoscaled ? null : 0,
        max: autoscaled ? null : 30,
        tickInterval: autoscaled ? null : 4
    });
});
```

#### Update

This appears to be an issue with all the even numbered plot bands! http://jsfiddle.net/StgHu/1/

Comment: Yeah, looks like a bug in update() function, reported [here](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1975). Thanks!